# Adobe Flash CC help removing movieclips end of scene

Tags: flash

I'm currently doing a part-time MA and have to create a project in Flash. I have a scene with a drag and drop but the 'dropped' elements carry over on top of the next scenes. I'm trying to use AS3 to set them to be removed once the 'next scene' button is clicked but no joy. I'd really appreciate some help with this!

I've seen people say online that I shouldn't be using scenes at all, that any objects should have been added in AS3 rather than dropped onto the stage in the timeline but unfortunately that's how I was shown and it may be too late to rebuild. What should I add to my AS to make it 'clear' the stage before going on to the next or previous scene?

```
var orig1X:Number=Object1_mc.x;
var orig1Y:Number=Object1_mc.y;
var orig2X:Number=Object2_mc.x;
var orig2Y:Number=Object2_mc.y;
var orig3X:Number=Object3_mc.x;
var orig3Y:Number=Object3_mc.y;
var orig4X:Number=Object4_mc.x;
var orig4Y:Number=Object4_mc.y;
var orig5X:Number=Object5_mc.x;
var orig5Y:Number=Object5_mc.y;


Object1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
Object1_mc.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, item1Release);


Object2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
Object2_mc.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, item2Release);


Object3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
Object3_mc.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, item3Release);


Object4_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
Object4_mc.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, item4Release);


Object5_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragTheObject);
Object5_mc.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, item5Release);


function dragTheObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target);
item.startDrag();
var topPos:uint=this.numChildren-1;
this.setChildIndex(item, topPos);
}

function item1Release(event:MouseEvent):void {
var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target);
item.stopDrag();
if (TargetObject1_mc.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) {
item.x=TargetObject1_mc.x;
item.y=TargetObject1_mc.y;
} else {
item.x=orig1X;
item.y=orig1Y;
} 
};


function item2Release(event:MouseEvent):void {
var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target);
item.stopDrag();
if (TargetObject2_mc.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) {
item.x=TargetObject2_mc.x;
item.y=TargetObject2_mc.y;
} else {
item.x=orig2X;
item.y=orig2Y;
} 
};


function item3Release(event:MouseEvent):void {
var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target);
item.stopDrag();
if (TargetObject3_mc.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) {
item.x=TargetObject3_mc.x;
item.y=TargetObject3_mc.y;
} else {
item.x=orig3X;
item.y=orig3Y;
} 
};


function item4Release(event:MouseEvent):void {
var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target);
item.stopDrag();
if (TargetObject4_mc.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) {
item.x=TargetObject4_mc.x;
item.y=TargetObject4_mc.y;
} else {
item.x=orig4X;
item.y=orig4Y;
} 
};


function item5Release(event:MouseEvent):void {
var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.target);
item.stopDrag();
if (TargetObject5_mc.hitTestPoint(item.x,item.y)) {
item.x=TargetObject5_mc.x;
item.y=TargetObject5_mc.y;
} else {
item.x=orig5X;
item.y=orig5Y;
} 
};
function reset(event:MouseEvent):void {
Object1_mc.x=orig1X;
Object1_mc.y=orig1Y;
Object2_mc.x=orig2X;
Object2_mc.y=orig2Y;
Object3_mc.x=orig3X;
Object3_mc.y=orig3Y;
Object4_mc.x=orig4X;
Object4_mc.y=orig4Y;
Object5_mc.x=orig5X;
Object5_mc.y=orig5Y;
}
Reset_btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);




Object1_mc.buttonMode = true;
Object2_mc.buttonMode = true;
Object3_mc.buttonMode = true;
Object4_mc.buttonMode = true;
Object5_mc.buttonMode = true;


button_12.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToPreviousScene_7);

function fl_ClickToGoToPreviousScene_7(event:MouseEvent):vo id
{
MovieClip(this.root).prevScene();
}



movieClip_13.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextScene_15);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextScene_15(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).nextScene();
}
```

Comment: Well it's hard to visualize a flexible structure if you put everything on the stage. Also shouldn't a new scene be clear anyways (like a new blank page) so we dont know what you're doing to make things carry over. Normally it wouldnt do that. Anyways one solution could be to create a container MovieClip (to act as a stage, holding the drag items) and then simply `removeChild` the MC when you go to next scene. Still feels weird to say that cos normally in the new scene it wouldn't / shouldn't be there...

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't know why these clips are carrying over. As you say the new scenes are clear so I don't know why they keep appearing. I've tried the removeChild as an extra function on clicking the next scene button and on the next scene but to no avail. I'm not so familiar with the parent/child relationship in Flash. Tutor was only showing us adding things to the stage from the library in different layers etc.

Comment: What's up with `MovieClip(this.root).nextScene();`? Does it help to just say  `nextScene();`? Or simply use `gotoAndStop(1, "Scene X");` where 1 is frame number in "Scene X" which is name of scene.

Comment: @Vc.One That MovieClip(this.root).nextScene(); is the code automatically added through code snippets in Flash when adding the mousevent to the button. It was working so didn't question it!

Comment: What's up with `MovieClip(this.root).nextScene();`? Does it help to just say  `nextScene();`? Or simply use `gotoAndStop(1, "Scene X");` where 1 is frame number in "Scene X" which is name of scene. If all else fails try **[this guide](http://www.dakmm.com/?p=333)** to adding your drag items from library into a movieClip by code. See also the (small) AS3 code at bottom. An example would be `var item1 : Dot = new Dot;` and to put into MC use `containerMC.addChild(item1);`. If you dont put into MC, use `removeChild(item1);` before `nextScene();`. With MC use `myMC.removeChild(item1);`

Comment: Okay. Try my above comment

Comment: Thank you very much VC.One. I'll give it a try later this evening.

Comment: Thanks VC.One. In the end it seemed t work by just using 'addChild' for the five different objects and then 'removeChild' on the next and previous scene buttons. I could swear I tried exactly that before but it all seems to have worked out now. Thanks again! (How do I upvote your or commend you for your help?)

Comment: Glad its working. The commending can only be done to an Answer (not comments). Don't worry about it for now. Just quietly wish me good karma and good luck with your project.